# Printing one element from data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to print out only the first element (first row, first column) of df4, using pandas. For some reason, iloc works just fine, but when I try to use loc, the error:

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Thank you for any help you can give!

```
df1  = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', index_col = 'col1')
df2  = pd.read_csv('mycsv2.csv', index_col = 'col1')
df3 = df1.sub(df2)
df4 = df3.div(df1)
print(df4.head())
percent_change = df4.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'], ascending=[1, 0])

print(percent_change.loc['0', 'col1'])
```

CSV code:

```
csv_data = get_ohlc(data_impor) #save returned list

#write csv

with open ("mycsv.csv", "w" , newline='' ) as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['col1', 'col2'])
    thewriter.writerows(csv_data) #write all data rows at the same time

with open('mycsv.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

time.sleep(0.2)

csv2_data = get_ohlc(data_impor) #save returned list

#write csv

with open ("mycsv2.csv", "w" , newline='' ) as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['col1', 'col2'])
    thewriter.writerows(csv2_data) #write all data rows at the same time

with open('mycsv2.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

The data for df4 is(they are zeroes cause the market is closed):

```
      col2
col1      
AAN    0.0
ABB    0.0
ABBV   0.0
ABM    0.0
ABT    0.0
ACP    0.0
``
Df1/df2 is:
```

```
    col2
```

col1
MMM   152.52
WBAI    3.54
WUBA   53.93
EGHT   15.47
AHC     1.66

Comment: Show your sample data

Answer (score 0):

percent_change = percent_change.loc['0'][0]